# How to retrieve wrong values submitted in a form?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using React and redux-form to create a form.
Behind I'm using Symfony 4.2 to validate data.

When I'm submitting the form and if I get errors, I don't know how I'm able to retrieve data to assign them in input again. Currently, my form is reset but I have error messages under the field.

Is it possible to retrieve field values after validations ?

Example of my form :

`<Field component={this.renderField} name="email" type="text" placeholder="ADRESSE EMAIL" />`

The render method :

```
renderField(data) {
    const hasError = data.meta.touched && !!data.meta.error;
    if (hasError) {
        data.input['aria-describedby'] = `user_${data.input.name}_helpBlock`;
        data.input['aria-invalid'] = true;
    }

    return <div className={`form-group${hasError ? ' has-error' : ''}`}>
        <label htmlFor={`user_${data.input.name}`} className="control-label">{data.input.label}</label>
        <input {...data.input} type={data.type} step={data.step} required={data.required} placeholder={data.placeholder} id={`user_${data.input.name}`}
             className={hasError ? "form-control is-invalid" : "form-control"}/>
        {hasError && <span className="invalid-feedback" id={`user_${data.input.name}_helpBlock`}>{data.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>;
}
```

Thanks for your help